# Spring WebFlux: Emit exception upon null value in Spring Data MongoDB reactive repositories?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to learn how to use MongoDB reactive repositories using `spring-boot 2.0.0.M2`, but I fear that I'm not doing things as intended.

This is one of my methods, which tries to find a `User` by their email. But if there is none, the method should throw an exception.

```
@Override
public Mono<User> findByEmail(String email) {
    User user = repository.findByEmail(email).block();
    if(user == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException("No user account was found with email: " + email);
    }
    return Mono.just(user);
}
```

The repository extends `ReactiveCrudRepository<User, String>`, but I fear that by using `.block()` I'm preventing this method from being reactive. I'm new to reactive programming, and I'm having a hard time to find good documentation on it. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Reactive programming requires a flow that is end-to-end reactive to gain the actual benefits that come from a reactive programming model. Calling `.block()` within the flow enforces synchronization and is considered an anti-pattern.

For your code, just propagate the `Mono` you obtain from `ReactiveCrudRepository` and apply the `switchIfEmpty` operator to emit an error signal if the `Mono` terminates without emitting a value. `null` values are not allowed in the Reactive Streams spec (the spec that Project Reactor is based on). If a result yields no value, then the `Publisher` does not emit a value.

```
@Override
public Mono<User> findByEmail(String email) {

    Mono<User> fallback = Mono.error(new NotFoundException("No user account was found with email: " + email));
    return repository.findByEmail(email).switchIfEmpty(fallback);
}
```

See also:

- [Going reactive with Spring Data](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/28/going-reactive-with-spring-data)
- [MiXiT site code built with Kotlin, WebFlux and Reactive Spring Data MongoDB repositories](https://github.com/mixitconf/mixit/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/mixit/web/handler/BlogHandler.kt)
- [Reactive microservices with Spring 5](https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/02/16/reactive-microservices-with-spring-5/)

Comment: Thanks, I had totally missed the switchIfEmpty(...) method.