# Spring WebFlux check user exists

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to check that the user has not been created yet before creating a new one, if there is then create an error... I found a similar question, but I can't remake it =(

[Spring WebFlux: Emit exception upon null value in Spring Data MongoDB reactive repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45365791/spring-webflux-emit-exception-upon-null-value-in-spring-data-mongodb-reactive-r)

```
  public Mono<CustomerDto> createCustomer(Mono<CustomerDto> dtoMono) {
    //How Create Mono error???
    Mono<Customer> fallback = Mono.error(new DealBoardException("Customer with email: " + dtoMono ???));

    return dtoMono.map(customerConverter::convertDto) //convert from DTO to Document
        .map(document -> {
          customerRepository.findByEmailOrPhone(document.getEmail(), document.getPhone())
        })
        .switchIfEmpty() //How check such customer doesn't exists?
        .map(document -> { //Filling in additional information from other services
          var customerRequest = customerConverter.convertDocumentToStripe(document);
          var customerStripe = customerExternalService.createCustomer(customerRequest);
          document.setCustomerId(customerStripe.getId());
          return document;
        })
        .flatMap(customerRepository::save) //Save to MongoDB
        .map(customerConverter::convertDocument); //convert from Document to Dto
  }
```

Comment: well one thing, you need to `return customerRepository.findByEmailOrPhone`

Comment: as @Toerktumlare mentioned `return` is missing. Also not sure why  fallback has type `Mono<Customer>`. To return error just use   `switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new DealBoardException("Customer with email: " + dtoMono ???)))` 
In addition I would revise decision of taking `Mono<CustomerDto>` as an input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm interested in the error, in the case of such an email || phone... For example how properly create Mono.erorr from Mono<CustomerDto> dtoMono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Mono<User> create(String username, String password) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(encoder.encode(password));
    return userRepo.existsUserByUsername(username)
            .flatMap(exists -> (exists) ? Mono.error(UserAlreadyExists::new) : userRepo.save(user));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following index declaration on the top of your `Customer` class:

```
@CompoundIndex(def = "{'email': 1, 'phone': 1}", unique = true)
```

That will prevent duplicate entries to be inserted in the database.

You can catch your `org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException` with the following construct:

```
customerService.save(newCustomer).onErrorMap(...);
```

Ref: [MongoDB Compound Indexes official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-compound/)